# Javascript forEach добавляет повторные вызовы на каждый элемент по размеру цикла

Tags: javascript, foreach, циклы

Добавляю addEventListener для массива элементов. Для этого использую функцию forEach:

```
var allDivs= document.querySelectorAll(".someDiv");
allDivs.forEach(function (e) {
    addEventListener("click", function () {
        alert('CLICKED');
    });
});
```

Если есть, например, 5 элементов. Почему в результате при клике на любом из них происходит вызов события 5 раз (5 раз вызывается alert), т.е. по количеству элементов в цикле?
Что неверно, или чего не хватает в коде, может использовать цикл `for(var el in allDivs)`...`el.addEven`...?

Comment: `addEventListener("click" ...` - контекст окна (добавляется 5 обработчиков на клик в любом месте). `e.addEventListener("click"` - контекст элемента

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы!!
По сути не пришла мысль, что "е" - это не всегда событие, иначе бы написал `...function(item){item.addEv...'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что данный вызов равносилен вызову

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(){...});
```

Таким образом было навешано пять одинаковых обработчиков на *один* элемент. Проверить что за элемент можно выведя *this*

```js
addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(this.toString());
});
```

При клике будет выведено *[object Window]*.

Для исправления, обработчик нужно навешивать текущему элементу. Он передается первым параметр в коллбэк функции `forEach`. В твоем случае - `e`, хотя лучше его переименовать, хотя бы в `el`, чтобы не путать с объектом передаваемым непосредственно в обработчик события.

```
allDivs.forEach(function (el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", function () {
        alert('CLICKED');
    });
});
```

Кроме того, не во всех браузерах для коллекции возвращаемой функцией *querySelectorAll* реализован метод *forEach*, поэтому перед его использованием лучше привести полученную коллекцию к массиву, либо использовать обычный *for*

```
var allDivs= document.querySelectorAll(".someDiv");
for(var i=0,i<allDivs.length;i++){
    allDivs[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        alert('CLICKED');
    });
};
```

Comment: "хотя лучше его переименовать, хотя бы в el, чтобы не путать с объектом передаваемым непосредственно в обработчик события." - а можно здесь поподробнее?

Comment: @smellyshovel, первый параметр в обработчике события - объект типа _Event_. Как правило его обозначают как `e`: `addEventListener("click", function (e) {...}`. В данном случае это не важно, так как в обработчике этот параметр не используется, но если бы он использовался - стало бы проблематично определять где элемент. а где event

Comment: Но автоматически же он не определяется как "e"?

Comment: @smellyshovel, конечно нет. Имена параметров функции описываются только в ее определении и могут быть любыми. Просто для обработчиков данное имя параметра наверное самое часто употребляемое

Comment: @Grundy
А не подскажете не лучше ли использовать `for(var el in allDivs)` вместо `for(var i=0,i<allDivs.length;i++){` да, жаль не могу forEach использовать - http://caniuse.com/#search=forEach IE только с 11 понимает... хотя пишу на CoffeeScript, который как бы должен учитывать кроссбраузерность, но так и пишет forEach...

Comment: @CodeGust, не лучше. Либо обычный for как в примере, либо получить массив из коллекции и с ним уже как угодно, тем же forEach

Comment: @Grundy
Понятно, спасиБо!

Answer (score 3):

Должно быть

```
e.addEventListener
```

Вы проходите по коллекции элементов, соответственно вам необходимо навесить обработчик на каждый из этих элементов. А вы, выходит, навешиваете на контекст `window`.