# Добавление через код событие кнопки с аргументом

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу массиву кнопкам, из 10 кнопок передать в событие OnClick метод Appropriation(i), с аргументом i, который будет увеличиваться. Суть: кнопка 1 имеет OnClick с Appropriation(1), кнопка 9 имеет OnClick с Appropriation(9). У меня выводится последняя итерация (9) на все кнопки, как сделать так что бы прибавлялись цифры

```
void Awake()
    {
        foreach (GameObject btn in  buttons)
          {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                btn.GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener(() => Appropriation(i) );
          }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не понял зачем тут два цикла. Хотя даже с одним был бы тот же результат. Т.к. lambda выполнялась бы уже тогда, когда текущее значение `i` было бы конечным (уже было бы 9). Поэтому надо "захватить" копию этого значения. Это можно сделать объявив новую переменную в цикле

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++) {
    int index = i;
    buttons[i].GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener(() => Appropriation(index));    
}
```

---

В *Javascript* тоже часто возникает подобная проблема при навешивании слушателя:

[Повесить обработчики событий в цикле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/272864/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5)

[Javascript forEach добавляет повторные вызовы на каждый элемент по размеру цикла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645399/javascript-foreach-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0)

Comment: Ошибся, там не 10 кнопок, там 19) просто цели разные. Спасибо большое за помощь